# Match all directories with a specific name in Apache's Directory directive

Tags: apache

I'm trying to deny access to all directories with the name `.git` anywhere on the system (unless explicitly allowed elsewhere in the configuration). I tried to solve this using wildcard matching but couldn't get it to work. My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file contains the following directives:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory **/.git>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

With this configuration file, I can still access `website.url.com/.git` from a web browser. I'm running Apache 2.4. I've also tried `*/.git` and that didn't work either. I've also tried swapping the order of the directives without success. What's the correct way to match the directory anywhere on the system or anywhere under `/var/www/`?